# How to Share on Facebook and Twitter App in Swift 3 without SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter, swift3

I need to share some link on facebook and twitter app if installed in device on a button tap.I can share the same using Whatsapp (code is below).I want to know if i can do the same in facebook and twitter app also.

```
  @IBAction func whatsappbtn(_ sender: UIButton) {

    var str = "This is the string which you want to share to WhatsApp"
    str=str.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: (NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed))!
    let whatsappURL = URL(string: "whatsapp://send?text=\(str)")
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(whatsappURL!) {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(whatsappURL!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
    } else {

        self.delegate?.alerting(msg: "Please install Whatsapp and try again.")

    }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are bound not to use FB / Twitter SDK . then you can try using activity controller and share from your app . Here you will get every possible share option .

```
 var activityViewController:UIActivityViewController?
 textField .text = "Some Test"

 @IBAction func shareText(sender: UIButton) {
    activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(
      activityItems: [textField.text as NSString],
      applicationActivities: nil)

    presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score -3):

First you need to get the FBSDK from Facebook's developer website.

Then you can do something like this:

```
   func shareToFacebook() {
        let inviteDialog = FBSDKAppInviteDialog()

        if inviteDialog.canShow() {

            guard let appLinkURL = URL(string: "YOUR LINK") else { return } 
            guard let previewImageURL = URL(string: "YOUR LINK IMAGE") else { return }

            let inviteContent = FBSDKAppInviteContent()
            inviteContent.appLinkURL = appLinkUrl
            inviteContent.appInvitePreviewImageURL = previewImageURL

            inviteDialog.content = inviteContent
            inviteDialog.delegate = self
            inviteDialog.show()
        }
    }
```

Don't forget to set the delegate methods:

```
  func appInviteDialog(_ appInviteDialog: FBSDKAppInviteDialog!, didCompleteWithResults results: [AnyHashable : Any]!) {
        print("Did complete sharing.. ")
    }

    func appInviteDialog(_ appInviteDialog: FBSDKAppInviteDialog!, didFailWithError error: Error!) {
        print("Error tool place in appInviteDialog \(error)")
    }
```

The above works for **Swift 3+**
Let me know if it works for you. Cheers